# Reactive over Services. Google REST architecture, RxJava

Tags: android, android-service, rx-java

Recently I've been investigating android enterprise development, which is mostly based on [Google's 2010 presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE). Also I've been looking into RxJava and stumbled upon this [presentation slide](http://www.slideshare.net/hazam/programming-sideways-asynchronous-techniques-for-android). Assuming that he means Android Service component, "Reactive over Services" sounds confusing to me.

Firstly, could you elaborate on this statement?

Secondly, I'm still looking for architecture patterns for android rest/enterprise applications, yet Google's pattern seems to be solid. Do you think it's still viable?

And thirdly, what about RxJava? How does it fit in this model?

Answer (score 2):

1. "services" is a retrofit term and has no connection to android.app.Service
2. and 3. you should look at https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue (inspired by the IO 2010 architecture but modernized) or a similar project with rxjava support: https://github.com/roman-mazur/async2014

... or just follow the official Google guide and use [a per-app singleton](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton).